# Why does Java allow many-many relationships?

Tags: java, associations, uml

I'm learning UML and have noticed that a platform specific model for Java allows many-many associations, I vaguely understand why but I;m just wondering if someone could explain with an example why this is so and why it is useful!

Comment: What does UML have to do with Java in the first place? The first one is a bloated modeling language for suits, and the latter is a programming language.

Comment: Every programming language allows many-to-many relationsships!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is had to due with Java but many-to-many associations are useful in modeling many thinks.

Let's say we have students and teachers.
Each teacher has many students and each student has many teachers. Obviously to model such a domain many-to-many relations come in handy.

Java is pretty flexible so it allows modeling of many-to-many relations (for example by adding Student[] array to Teacher class and Teacher[] array to Student class definition - for Student-Teacher example) through I don't know any special support that Java provides for easy modeling of such relations.